# About the drawing speed

Tags: android, performance, canvas, drawing

I want to draw the 2000 points which save to data object.

I use the following code:

```
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(2000,100，Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas canvasTemp=new Canvas(bitmap);
Paint paint=new Paint();
for (int i = 0; i < 2000; i++) {
canvasTemp.drawPoint(i, data.getData(i), paint);
}
   Matrix matrix = new Matrix(); 
    float scaleWidth = ((float) 640 / 2000);   
float scaleHeight = ((float) 480/ 100);   
matrix.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);   
 Bitmap newbmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0,2000, 100, matrix, true);   
canvas.drawBitmap(newbmp, 0, 0, new Paint());
```

This drawing speed is too slow. It needs about 5 or 6 seconds.

How to make the drawing speed more quickly?

Comment: What are you doing in your `data.getData()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not directly paint on the canvas? It saves you creating two (large) bitmaps:

```
Paint paint=new Paint();
Matrix matrix = new Matrix(); 
float scaleWidth = ((float) 640 / 2000);   
float scaleHeight = ((float) 480/ 100);   
matrix.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);   
canvast.concat(matrix);
for (int i = 0; i < 2000; i++) {
  canvas.drawPoint(i, data.getData(i), paint);
}
```

Just use [`concat()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#concat%28android.graphics.Matrix%29) to scale the draw commands of the canvas.

Additional note: Creating new objects (`paint`, `matrix`, two large! bitmaps) in the draw method of a `View` is not recommended. It results in lots of instance creations/deletions, which result in activating the garbage collector (GC) more often, resulting in (huge) performance issues with your application!

Instead, create the `paint` and `matrix` object once, in the constructor of your `View`.